# Function using columns in arguments of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am trying to create a function with one of column of my dataframe outplacement, because similar calculations I would need for other columns also.

```
numeric_fun<-function(dataset,grp_var,var){

  require("dplyr")

    dataset%>%select(grp_var,var)%>% group_by_(grp_var)%>%
  summarize(
    'q25' = quantile(var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[2],
    'median' =round(quantile(var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[3],0),
    'avg' = round( mean(var, na.rm=TRUE), 0),
    'q75' = quantile(var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[4] ,
    'n' = sum(!is.na(var))
  )%>% 
  mutate(
    q25 = ifelse( n < 5, "--", paste(q25,"%" )),
    median = ifelse( n < 5, "--", paste(median,"%")),
    avg = ifelse(n < 5, "--", paste(avg,"%")),
    q75 = ifelse( n < 5, "--", paste(q75,"%")),
    n = n
  ) %>% 
  rename( "Industry"=grp_var,
          "25%" = q25,
          "75%" = q75
  )

}

numeric_fun(outplacement,"Q7_1","Q8")
```

But this ones is not working, any other efficient ways?

output of dput

```
structure(list(Q7_1 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 14L, NA, 
1L, 9L, 13L, 1L, NA, 3L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 2L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 
11L, NA, 1L, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, 5L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 13L, 10L, 
13L, 13L, NA, 11L, NA, 1L, 11L, NA, 5L, NA, 1L, NA, 9L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 10L, 1L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 6L, 6L, NA, 13L, 14L, NA, 
NA, 14L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 12L, 13L, NA, 3L, 11L, 3L, 11L, 1L, 
NA, 9L, NA, 10L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 13L, 4L, 14L, NA, 13L), .Label = c("Banking/Financial Services", 
"Chemicals", "Consumer Goods", "Energy", "High Tech", "Insurance/Reinsurance", 
"Life Sciences", "Logistics", "Mining & Metals", "Other Manufacturing", 
"Other Non-Manufacturing", "Retail & Wholesale", "Services (Non-Financial)", "Transportation Equipment"), class = "factor"), Q8 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, NA, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, NA, 3L, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 1L, 5L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L, NA, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 
NA, 3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, NA, 5L), Q9 = c(3L, 1L, 
NA, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 3L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA, 1L, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L), Q10 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 
NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 
1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-94L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 
0x0000000000090788>, .Names = c("Q7_1", 
"Q8", "Q9", "Q10"))
```

Comment: Right now you are feeding a character string (the content of `var`, which is `"Q7_1"`) to functions like `mean`, which expect a numeric vector. `dplyr` can work with these character strings for `select` and similar functions, but `quantile` and `mean` can't.

Comment: Try with `enquo/quo_name` and `!!`

Comment: I am using two columns here, one for grouping 'grp_var' and other numeric column 'var'. Q7_1 is the variable I need for grouping the output. Mean and all other calculations I am performing on other numeric columns. Please let me know if there is any other way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `enquo/!!` from `dplyr` we can remodel the function as

```
library(dplyr)
numeric_fun<-function(dataset,grp_var,var){

      grp_var <- enquo(grp_var)
      var <- enquo(var)


    dataset %>%
          select(!! grp_var, !!var) %>%
          group_by(!! grp_var) %>%
          summarise(
               q25 = quantile(!! var,  type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[2],
           median =round(quantile(!! var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[3],0),
               avg = round( mean(!! var, na.rm=TRUE), 0),
               q75 = quantile(!! var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[4] ,
               n = sum(!is.na(!!var))) %>%

         mutate(
              q25 = ifelse( n < 5, "--", paste0(q25,"%" )),
              median = ifelse( n < 5, "--", paste0(median,"%")),
              avg = ifelse(n < 5, "--", paste0(avg,"%")),
              q75 = ifelse( n < 5, "--", paste0(q75,"%"))

          ) %>% 
        rename(Industry= !!grp_var,
          `25%` = q25,
          `75%` = q75
  )



}
```

-run the function

```
numeric_fun(df1, Q7_1, Q8)
# A tibble: 14 x 6
#   Industry                   `25%` median avg   `75%`     n
#   <fctr>                     <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 Banking/Financial Services 2%    3%     4%    5%       11
# 2 Chemicals                  --    --     --    --        3
# 3 Consumer Goods             1%    3%     3%    5%        5
# 4 Energy                     --    --     --    --        4
# 5 High Tech                  1%    4%     3%    4.5%      6
# 6 Insurance/Reinsurance      --    --     --    --        3
# 7 Logistics                  --    --     --    --        2
# 8 Mining & Metals            --    --     --    --        4
# 9 Other Manufacturing        --    --     --    --        4
#10 Other Non-Manufacturing    2%    2%     3%    4.75%     8
#11 Retail & Wholesale         --    --     --    --        2
#12 Services (Non-Financial)   2%    3%     3%    5%       12
#13 Transportation Equipment   --    --     --    --        3
#14 <NA>                       --    --     --    --        0
```

Comment: It also needs rlang and data.table.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck  The functions `enquo` are loaded without explicitly calling `rlang`

Comment: Just checked the NAMESPACE file of dplyr on github and you are correct.  rlang must be installed but it does not have to be loaded.  data.table must still be loaded since the input is data.table.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the code was using character strings in inappropriate contexts.  We can use `sym` and !! from the rlang package to translate them.  Add the statements marked with `##`and then use `!!grp_var` and `!!var` in place of `grp_var` and `var` everywhere.  Also changed `group_by_` to `group_by`, reformatted, changed the `require` to `library` (see next paragraph) and added `library` statements for data.table and rlang.

Note that `library` is preferable to `require` unless within an `if`. That way if the package is missing it will fail at the `library` statement making the cause obvious.  On the other hand with `require` it will fail further down making it harder to debug.

```
library(data.table) ##
library(dplyr)


numeric_fun <- function(dataset, grp_var, var) {

  grp_var <- sym(grp_var)
  var <- sym(var)

  dataset %>%
    select(!!grp_var,!!var) %>% 
    group_by(!!grp_var) %>%
    summarize(
      'q25' = quantile(!!var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm = TRUE)[2],
      'median' = round(quantile(!!var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[3],0),
      'avg' = round( mean(!!var, na.rm = TRUE), 0),
      'q75' = quantile(!!var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm = TRUE)[4] ,
      'n' = sum(!is.na(!!var))
    ) %>% 
    mutate(
      q25 = ifelse( n < 5, "--", paste(q25, "%" )),
      median = ifelse( n < 5, "--", paste(median, "%")),
      avg = ifelse(n < 5, "--", paste(avg, "%")),
      q75 = ifelse( n < 5, "--", paste(q75, "%")),
      n = n
    ) %>% 
    rename( "Industry" = !!grp_var,
            "25%" = q25,
            "75%" = q75
    )

}

numeric_fun(outplacement,"Q7_1","Q8")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 6
   Industry                   `25%` median avg   `75%`      n
   <fctr>                     <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <int>
 1 Banking/Financial Services 2 %   3 %    4 %   5 %       11
 2 Chemicals                  --    --     --    --         3
 3 Consumer Goods             1 %   3 %    3 %   5 %        5
 4 Energy                     --    --     --    --         4
 5 High Tech                  1 %   4 %    3 %   4.5 %      6
 6 Insurance/Reinsurance      --    --     --    --         3
 7 Logistics                  --    --     --    --         2
 8 Mining & Metals            --    --     --    --         4
 9 Other Manufacturing        --    --     --    --         4
10 Other Non-Manufacturing    2 %   2 %    3 %   4.75 %     8
11 Retail & Wholesale         --    --     --    --         2
12 Services (Non-Financial)   2 %   3 %    3 %   5 %       12
13 Transportation Equipment   --    --     --    --         3
14 <NA>                       --    --     --    --         0
```

### Note

`dput` does not work with objects having external pointers such as data.table objects so we used this:

```
outplacement <- 
structure(list(Q7_1 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 14L, NA, 
1L, 9L, 13L, 1L, NA, 3L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 2L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 
11L, NA, 1L, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, 5L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 13L, 10L, 
13L, 13L, NA, 11L, NA, 1L, 11L, NA, 5L, NA, 1L, NA, 9L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 10L, 1L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 6L, 6L, NA, 13L, 14L, NA, 
NA, 14L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 12L, 13L, NA, 3L, 11L, 3L, 11L, 1L, 
NA, 9L, NA, 10L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 13L, 4L, 14L, NA, 13L), .Label = c("Banking/Financial Services", 
"Chemicals", "Consumer Goods", "Energy", "High Tech", "Insurance/Reinsurance", 
"Life Sciences", "Logistics", "Mining & Metals", "Other Manufacturing", 
"Other Non-Manufacturing", "Retail & Wholesale", "Services (Non-Financial)", "Transportation Equipment"), class = "factor"), Q8 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, NA, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, NA, 3L, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 1L, 5L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L, NA, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 
NA, 3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, NA, 5L), Q9 = c(3L, 1L, 
NA, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 3L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA, 1L, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L), Q10 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 
NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 
1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-94L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Q7_1", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10"))

library(data.table)
outplacement <- as.data.table(outplacement)
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in your function i.e. before the `rename` the `#%>%` is commented

Comment: I am trying create function for categorical variables using table() function. and in this case how do I pass the variables. enquo and sym would not work in this case. Data is same - outplacement.

 T1.1<-with(data,table(!!grp_var,!!var))

Comment: tidyeval/rlang constructs can mostly only be used with packages that support them such as dplyr; otherwise, as a rule you should *not* use non-standard evaluation.  Rather than pass `Type` in the following example, pass `"Type"`, i.e. a character string: `mytab <- function(data, var) table(data[[var]]); mytab(CO2, "Type")`

Comment: Actually yes its working after I added "Type" for two variables also, Thanks